# Index of minimal value of selected elements from a python numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array (a) and a mask array (m), how can I get the index of minimal value? e.g., if `a = [3, 2, 4, 5]` and `m = [1, 0, 0, 1]`, the expected answer is 1 because among the 2nd and 3rd elements, the minimal value is the 2nd element (index 1).
My solution (seems awkward):

```
index = np.where(m == 0)[0]
point = index[np.argmin(a[index])]
```

Are there better solutions? Thanks.

Comment: That code is compact, reasonably efficient, and easy to understand.  If you want something "better" please define the criteria you're trying to optimize.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? This code works, right? The time complexity is O(n), and you can't get better than that, though you probably can reduce the constant factor.

Comment: The mask looks back-to-front to me. Shouldn't it be `[0, 1, 1, 0]`?

Comment: @roganjosh: The NumPy mask convention is that 1 means "ignore this location."

Comment: @JohnZwinck really? But that's completely at odds with a boolean mask?

Comment: @roganjosh: Yes, really.  If you think about it, a "mask" is what covers things and makes them invisible.  So to some people, the "True" parts of a mask would naturally be the places where it performs its function, namely masking out values.  See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html

Comment: @JohnZwinck I use numpy a lot and would never have considered it that way, but I can see the logic in it. I don't think I ascribe to it, but thanks for letting me know so that I'm at least aware :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck ah, now I understand sorry, I think wires got crossed. That link is for an explicit mask where the convention absolutely makes sense. In this case, the OP is using "mask" in place of "filter" (in the form of `where`), which would filter based on bools.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. I think the code looks awkward (and seems that it goes through the array for multiple times), so I'm wondering whether there's a function from numpy/scipy to achieve my goal (in this way, maybe I can make fully use of the optimization provided by numpy). I've considered `numpy.ma` but it seems that `argmin` from `numpy.ma` will fill the array with a specific value, thus cannot be used here (there might be np.inf in the array so we cannot fill the array with np.inf).

Comment: If the range of possible values for `a` is small, then a hack would be `np.argmin(a+m*k)` where `k` is a large enough number

Comment: @Dan, your hack will not work for a special case such as `a = [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf]`, `mask=[1, 0, 0]`, for which OP wants to get 1 and not 0. See my updated answer and the comments.

Answer (score 0):

What about using masked array?

```
np.ma.array(a, mask=m).argmin()
```

Example:

```
>>> a = [0, np.inf, 1, 2]
>>> m = [1, 0, 0, 1]
>>> np.ma.array(a, mask=m).argmin()
2
```

**Update**: Based on your comment, to achieve what you want you could use [np.nan_to_num](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) on `a` to replace infinities with the largest finite floating point value representable by `a.dtype`, i.e. `np.finfo(a.dtype).max`. Keep in mind that this function also replaces NaN's with 0, so you might want to mask them out or replace with some other value.

```
>>> a = [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf]
>>> m = [1, 0, 0]
>>> a_masked = np.ma.array(np.nan_to_num(a), mask=m)
>>> a_masked.argmin()
1
```

**Update 2:** The problem seems to be that if all the unmasked values of a masked array are inf's, then `argmin` always returns 0:

```
>>> m = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
>>> a = [10, 9, np.inf, 8, np.inf]
>>> a_masked = np.ma.array(a, mask=m)   
>>> a_masked.argmin()
0
```

Is this a bug or is it intentional? In any case, to deal with this we could first check if `np.isinf(a_masked).all()` is True and then do the rest.

Here are two functions to achieve the task:

```
def argmin_ma(a, m):
    if np.all(m):
        return None    
    a_masked = np.ma.array(a, mask=m)    
    if np.isinf(a_masked).all():    
        #a_masked = np.ma.array(np.nan_to_num(a), mask=m)
        #return a_masked.argmin()
        return np.argmin(m)
    return a_masked.argmin()

def argmin_ma2(a, m):
    if np.all(m):
        return None 
    a = np.asarray(a)
    m = np.aasrray(m)
    index = np.where(m == 0)[0]
    return index[np.argmin(a[index])]
```

Imho the second version proposed by OP looks better, and more importantly it is faster:

```
N = 10000 
m = np.random.randint(2, size=N)
a = np.random.randint(N, size=N)*1.0
np.put(a, np.random.choice(range(N), N//2, replace=False), np.inf)

%timeit argmin_ma(a, m)
532 µs ± 70.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit argmin_ma2(a, m)
132 µs ± 6.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: See the above comments. I've considered `numpy.ma` but it seems that argmin from `numpy.ma` will fill the array with a specific value, thus cannot be used here (there might be np.inf in the array so we cannot fill the array with np.inf).

Comment: `np.argmin(np.ma.array([np.inf, np.inf, np.inf], mask=[1, 0, 0])) = 0`

Comment: underlying array a is not changed. what is problem with fiilling np.inf. anyways infinite value cannot be minimum. Nor two infinite value can be compared

Comment: Apologies I can't understand your point. For the above example, I need to get 1 (and I think it's reasonable to get 1). This is why I can't use `np.ma.array`.

Comment: Yes, your new approach doesn't seems acceptable (and seems buggy when we have numbers > 1e20). Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: @Hanmin Qin, I updated the answer. Now I think it achieves what you want.

Comment: @AndyK I don't think your latest solution is correct, see

    a = [np.inf, np.inf, np.nan_to_num(np.inf)]
    m = [1, 0, 0]
    a_masked = np.ma.array(np.nan_to_num(a), mask=m)
    # will output 1, the expected output is 2
    np.argmin(a_masked)

Comment: That is, when `a = [np.inf, np.inf, np.nan_to_num(np.inf)]` and `m = [1, 0, 0]`, your solution will output 1 while the expected output should be 2